# Karma Load remote spec files

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

i have a several bitbucket repositories and i want to have karma configuration files in only one repository. Then if i run karma in that repository i want it load the spec files from the others repositories.

So if i run karma on the repo A, i want to load the spec files from repos B,C,D... and get the results.

I tried with the files, host and basepath on the config file to try load them from bitbucket but nothing happens, even an error.

My question: is that possible and how??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisites

- Git Installed on local machine
- NPM installed on local machine

Steps

1. Start
2. Make a new Folder on your local machine.

> mkdir folder_name

3. Initialize a new git repository in new Folder

> git init

4. Move inside the folder using

> cd "folder_name"

5. You can clone all the repositories to your system using

> ```
> git clone RepoA.git
>
> git clone RepoB.git
>
> git clone RepoC.git
> ```

6. Initialize the karma and install the karma and its related dependencies to parent Repository by creating karma-config.js
7. Make all your configurations among the repositories and start karma
8. Now you can test on all the repositories together on your local machine.

> karma start test/karma-conf.js --single-run
>
> karma start test/karma-conf.js --auto-watch